# Java How to create an array with a custom name in a module, can it be done?

Tags: java, arrays, module

I am trying to make a library with all sorts of useful array manipulation. Is there any way I can set a module up that makes a custom array with a custom name? Here's what I've thought of, but obviously doesn't work.

```
public static void CreateArray(String type, String name, int length){
    if (type.equalsIgnoreCase("int")){
        int[] name = new int[length];
    } else if (type.equalsIgnoreCase("double")){
        double[] name = new double[length];
    }
}
```

I'm getting errors when I call the variable name for obvious reasons. Is there any way I could do this, or do I have to make arrays manually (boo hoo!)

Comment: No I guess, But why you run in to this problem ? There is no real world situation like this *afaik*.

Comment: Making arrays manually is a way better option than using some "createArray" method in a library made by you. What drugs are you on? And by the way, no it's not possible in any case.

Comment: I'm on creativity, my friend. I was just trying to make a wonderful library, so I'll just go back to doing it manually. also, Suresh, there is a use if you want to make a new array based on user input!

Comment: User can give inputs what the array values can contains, not the reference name which are maintaining in the code.

Comment: @Kyle There's a difference between wonderful and useless. You can create arrays dynamically of course, but if you think you'll be able to create the name of a variable dynamically, you're lacking in the basics (and almost certainly unqualified to write a useful library). If you can tell us what problem you're looking to solve, we can advise you on that.

Comment: I was just thinking about it, and it would be really awesome, and really useless, if Oracle released a new variable for code. Absolutely useless, but hey, it's cool! I never expected to make the name a variable, but a man can dream.

Comment: @Kyle `user input` -> the only user I can think of in this case is a programmer and thus you are actually trying to implement a feature which every programming language already has. And Yes Oracle (actually sun) has already released something like that and its name is `java` ;-)

Answer (score 0):

There is no possible way without actual byte code injections using stuff like asm libraries for java.

*If I remember that correctly*

The errors occur because the variable name is a **String** type from the method decleration (its parameters)

You can not use a dynamic variable name.
The variable must be what you set it to.

So when you declare an int array or double array of name. It will error because name is already declared as another data type.